# How to separate data by user name in Angular 9+?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9

I am trying to separate data by a user name with their respective column of data.
I have different Changeable users with their data. I want to display data in the table. I am not able to do that..

[image: Screen shot of console data]

I want to display users in Name1 Name2... and their data(Cash, PhonePay, Card, etc) respectively.

**HTML file**

```
<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
    <thead class="table-primary">
        <tr>
            <th class="th-sm text-danger">Division:</th>
            <th class="th-sm">Name 1</th>
            <th class="th-sm">Name 2</th>
            <th class="th-sm">Name 3</th>
            <th class="th-sm">Name 4</th>
            <th class="th-sm">Name 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="th-sm">Cash</th>
            <td class="th-sm">0</td>
            <td class="th-sm">0</td>
            <td class="th-sm">0</td>
            <td class="th-sm">00</td>
            <td class="th-sm">00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="th-sm">Phone Pay</th>
            <td class="th-sm">0</td>
            <td class="th-sm">0</td>
            <td class="th-sm">0</td>
            <td class="th-sm">00</td>
            <td class="th-sm">00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="th-sm">Card</th>
            <td class="th-sm">0</td>
            <td class="th-sm">0</td>
            <td class="th-sm">0</td>
            <td class="th-sm">0</td>
            <td class="th-sm">00</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th class="th-sm">Cell Pay</th>
            <td class="th-sm">0</td>
            <td class="th-sm">0</td>
            <td class="th-sm">0</td>
            <td class="th-sm">0</td>
            <td class="th-sm">00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="th-sm">Total</th>
            <td class="th-sm">0</td>
            <td class="th-sm">0</td>
            <td class="th-sm">0</td>
            <td class="th-sm">0</td>
            <td class="th-sm">00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**TS FILE**

```
getSalesData() {
 console.log(this.cnvForm.value);
 this.salesService.getSalesCollectionVariance(this.cnvForm.value).subscribe(data => {
  this.recObj = data;
  console.log(this.recObj);
  this.filterData(data);
 });
}
```

I have data in the console but I have no any idea how to place/display respective data in the HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

the following code will build your table based on your dynamic data array, your thead should look like this

```
<thead class="table-primary">
    <tr>
        <th class="th-sm text-danger">Division:</th>
        <th class="th-sm" *ngFor="let item of data;let index = index;">{{item?.user}}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

and body

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <th class="th-sm">Cash</th>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data; let i=index;">
    <td class="th-sm">{{item?.cash}}</td>
  </ng-container>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th class="th-sm">Phone Pay</th>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data;let i=index;">
    <td class="th-sm">{{item?.phonePay}}</td>
  </ng-container>
 </tr>
 ...
```

Comment: I got an error: Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 7 in [Name{{index=1}}] in D:/angular/src/app/collection_variance/collection-variance/collection-variance.component.html@72:99 ("
                                    <th class="th-sm" *ngFor="let item of data;let index = index;">[ERROR ->]Name{{index=1}}</th>
                                    <th class="th-sm" *ngFor="let item of data;l"): D:/angular/project/kkmart/src/app/collection_variance/collection-variance/collection-variance.component.html@72:99   ???

Comment: i fixed it sorry, it's index+1 to make it start from 1, since index start from 0 so it's Name{{index+1}}

Comment: Its not working..  Its just hide my column where i have place your code.

Comment: i'm 100% sure that it works , check the code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kjguyz?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I want to display user name i.e. daniel, saurav in place of Name 1, Name 2,  not only Name 1, Name 2. And display their respective data (Net amnt ) in card, CreditCard respectively.. See the screenshot and u will be more clear..

Comment: The idea is correct , in that case you have only to access properties in your item! check my update

Comment: when i changed data to recObj i.e.*ngFor="let item of recObj then it worked for only user name but not worked in net amnt, creditCard ....  Do u have any idea... We are nearer to solve these problems..